# How to show the grand total of a column in repeater control of asp.net using C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am a beginner in asp.net so I am developing a software in which I want to sum up the the column of total price e.g I have 1,2,3(these values are coming from SQL database) values in total price column and I want to sum up these values (as the result after summing up them is 6) and show the grand total of this column in the footer template of repeater control. I am very grateful if somebody tells me.

Thankyou!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
     int total = 0;
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            //using findcontrol method the label and get the amount
            total += Convert.ToInt32(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("ltrlAmount")).Text);
             
            //
        }
        else if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");
            lbl.Text = total.toString(); //set value
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you posted this answer to the wrong question? Really has nothing to do with the OP's question (plus the question, as written, is off-topic as it has no code and is just a general requirement). Also, in the future, please add text to your answers to explain how they answer the question, vs just a block of code.